# How to correctly supply argument to the following Python script

Tags: python, linux, command-line, arguments

I'm new to Python and would really like to run some files through the following Python script.

https://github.com/ashutoshkpandey/Variants_call/blob/master/Filter_Pindel_del_vcf.py

I'm running on Linux server and Python is installed.  I saved the script in a directory with the two required files (Del.vcf and Output_D).  Here is what I've typed on the command line but the script can't find the files for some reason.

```
$ python Filter_Pindel_del_vcf.py Del.vcf, Output_D, Outputfile

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Filter_Pindel_del_vcf.py", line 45, in <module>
    for row in fileinput.input([Filepath]):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 253, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 345, in readline
    self._file = open(self._filename, self._mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Del.vcf,'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove commas:

```
python Filter_Pindel_del_vcf.py Del.vcf Output_D Outputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

This script uses positional arguments. Just lose the commas and you should be fine:

```
$ python Filter_Pindel_del_vcf.py Del.vcf Output_D Outputfile
```